# How to access the value of EditText added in ToolBar

Tags: android, android-layout

I have added an EditText in the toolbar of my layout. I want to access the value of EditText when done is pressed from the soft keyboard. I have initialized the EditText in the onCreate() of my activity. I want to access this EditText value and feed to my api call.

here ismy xml layout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Toolbar" >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/search_edit_text"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_text_cursor"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
             />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_ff"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_ff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/stat_no_connection"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/prog_bar_ff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/nothing_to_show_here"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/stat_nothing_gray"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

and this is my onCreate()

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Intent intent = this.getIntent()
        mUserEmail = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.USER_EMAIL);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_list_activity);
        RecyclerView mRecy = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_ff);
        mProgBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prog_bar_ff);
        mRecy.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_ff);
        nothingToShow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.nothing_to_show_here);

        Toolbar  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

        /* Common toolbar setup */
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);
        Log.d(TAG+"init","search");
        mQueryString = searchEditText.getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG+"mQuery",mQueryString);
        searchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    Log.d(TAG+"mQuery",mQueryString);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new OfferAdapter(this);
        mRecy.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

`

Comment: searchEditText.getText()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `searchEditText` is in toolbar so get from toolbar.

```
  Toolbar  toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
  searchEditText = (EditText) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text);

  done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            String value = searchEditText.getText().toString();
            }
        });
```

Comment: searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edit_text); is also correct.

Comment: Thank you so much dude..I got the result...Thank you very much